# google cloud messaging register (serive not available error)

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am getting this error while trying to register with GCM. 
My AVD target is Android 4.2.2 and API level is 17. 
Please find the stack trace below.

```
07-11 14:17:58.577: W/System.err(800): java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
07-11 14:17:58.577: W/System.err(800):  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
07-11 14:17:58.577: W/System.err(800):  at com.exp.code.utils.AsyncRequestWeb.doInBackground(AsyncRequestWeb.java:99)
07-11 14:17:58.577: W/System.err(800):  at com.exp.code.utils.AsyncRequestWeb.doInBackground(AsyncRequestWeb.java:1)
07-11 14:17:58.577: W/System.err(800):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-11 14:17:58.577: W/System.err(800):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-11 14:17:58.590: W/System.err(800):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-11 14:17:58.590: W/System.err(800):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-11 14:17:58.598: W/System.err(800):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-11 14:17:58.609: W/System.err(800):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any suggestions? 
I am stuck on this for a long time. Is it the problem of the firewall blocking the ports or issue with the code....

Answer (score 0):

SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE occurs if GCM server could not be located.

This can be due to Network Issues.Check if Internet is Accessible though your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your AVD target must be Google APIs